# Is it possible to make a web installer for an Android/iOs app?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, installation

okay, its a general question, is it possible to make a web installer ( a single apk file hosted on the play store or app store which on execution, download the code and resources from my own web server, the apk file will just act like a downloader or something like that) for an app on Play Store or in App Store? the main concern is, I don't want some crackers to access and break into the app for the premium version of the app.

have anyone tried or heard of this kinda app distribution? or any app/developers use this method to deliver the app? (guess some games do?)

PS. web installers have some advantages of controlling the older versions and also can reduce the apk file size as I guess the low pixel density resources only need to be delivered to devices with low density displays. ie, the resources(icons and stuff) for a low end device does not need to be delivered to a high or middle or extra high end device and vice versa. plus developer dont need to worry about offline app transfers thus each download can be counted. but a disadvantage of heavy use of server.

thanks, for any views, guidelines or suggestions.
NB- Its not a web app. the Java coded app for android and Objective C coded app for iOs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, if you're wanting to distribute the entire application from your website without using the App Store it's not possible as a general rule.  The two exceptions being:

1. If you get an Enterprise developer's account from Apple, then you can prepare installation packages that will work from a web site.  However, you may only distribute the application to direct employees.
2. For testing stages you can prepare ad-hoc releases and then work with a company such as TestFlight.  If you take this approach you're limited to release to 100 devices per year and each release is only valid for 3 months.  You can't remove devices from the list except on the anniversary date of your developer account.

If you're actually wanting to put the installer application in the App Store and then download the actual Application, it's not allowed under any circumstances.  The ToS prohibit you from having an application which downloads executable code or script (with the implicit exception of a web application)

Comment: thank you so much David, for this info. Would love to hear about the Android part, if you know anything about that,